# The Frechet derivative of $\sin(xy)$ at $(\pi,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is the Frechet derivative of $\sin(xy)$ at the point $(\pi,0)$ equal to the the linear function $\phi(x,y)=\pi y$?

The Frechet derivative of $xy$ at $(a,b)$ is $bx+ay$ and so the Frechet derivative of $\sin(xy)$ must $\cos(ab)(bx+ay)$. Is it correct?

However the limit with which the Frechet derivative is defiend:

$$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin((a+s)(b+t))-\sin(ab)-\cos(ab)(bs+at)}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}$$
[does not exists](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28sin%28pi*t%2Bst%29-pi+*t%29%2Fsqrt%28s%5E2%2Bt%5E2%29+as+%28s%2Ct%29-%3E%280%2C0%29) when $(a,b)=(\pi,0)$:
$$\lim_{(s,t)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(\pi t+st)-\pi t}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing out the expansion of $\sin(xy)$ about $(\pi,0)$, we have
$$\sin(xy)=\sin(\pi\cdot0)+D[\sin(xy)\rvert_{(\pi,0)}\cdot(x-\pi,y)+\mathcal{O}(\|(x-\pi,y)\|^2).$$
Where the Fréchet derivative is the linear functional $$D[\sin(xy)\rvert_{(\pi,0)}=(y\cos(xy),x\cos(xy))\rvert_{(\pi,0)}=(0,\pi)\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$$
Thus you are correct. In short, for a differentiable function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, the Fréchet derivative is simply the gradient.

Comment: So why the limit with which the frechet derivative is defined, fails to exist?

Answer (score 1):

Set $\cos \phi =\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}$

Then you have

$\frac{\sin(\pi t+st)-\pi t}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}=\frac{\pi t+st-\pi t+O((\pi t+st)^3)}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}=\frac{st+O((\pi t+st)^3)}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}=t\cos \phi + \frac{O((\pi t+st)^3)}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}}\rightarrow 0\ $as $(s,t)\rightarrow 0$.